# Prevent /dev/null/ from dumping when running git diff

Tags: git, diff

When I try to dump differences between two folders with

```
git diff --no-index --name-only folder1 folder2 > diff.txt
```

I encounter a lot of **/dev/null** strings. It shows the removed folders as far as I know. But I don't need those in my file. How can I prevent it from dumping?

Comment: Could you use `git diff ... | grep -v /dev/null > diff.txt` to filter out the lines you do not want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `-D` aka `--irreversible-delete` ([manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--D)). It will not show the content of deleted files, but still show that the file was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can add the [`--diff-filter=d` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203), to exclude deleted paths

```
git diff --no-index --name-only --diff-filter=d folder1 folder2
```